# Jquery scroll to id from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div with id="home-features" on home page.
When I click on menu with class="about-us-scrolling" it scrolls to div with id="home-features"
But how do scroll from another page to home page and scroll to div id="home-features"

I need

1. go to home page (mywebsite.com)
2. scroll to div id="home-features"

I use this code for scrolling to div id="home-features" when I am on homepage

```
jQuery(".about-us-scrolling").click(function() {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("#home-features").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

How to change it for other pages?

Comment: link to `https://mywebsite.com/#home-features"` or `https://mywebsite.com/index.html#home-features"` depending on your homepage url

Comment: "*how to change it for other pages*" - copy the js to those other pages?

Comment: @freedomn-m they want to link to the div from other pages

Comment: @mplungjan that's quite possibly/likely what they *want* - but it's not what they've described.   They've described what it already does as what they want, then added *"I use this code - how to change "it" for other pages"*.   So the stated question is that they want to change that code on other pages... Needs clarity.

Comment: It is very clear to me.  `I use this when I am ON the homepage, But how do scroll from another page to home page and scroll to div id="home-features" - How to change it for other pages?`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to the home page and when you navigate to the home page just add a hash to `id` of the `div` you want to scroll to.

ex:

```
<a href="./home.html#home-features">Home</a>
```